# Magento 2.3.3 set product as New date issue

Tags: product, admin, magento2.3.3

I am having an issue with Magento 2.3.3 and set up as new to Date.

Although I set the date in a product in admin, if I go back to the product and press save the date for set up product as new to is gone.
This is really strange.
So I thought to create a simple module to keep that date just before saving the product. Also I inserted a function to give the product if the date is not set 90days + the date is when you save. But it isn't working and I don't see any errors in logs

My code is:

```
namespace MyModule\DatesFix\Plugin\Backend\Magento\Catalog\Model;

/**
 * Class Product
 * @package Mymodule\DatesFix\Plugin\Backend\Magento\Catalog\Model
 */
class Product
{

    /**
     * Before save
     *
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject
     *
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function beforeBeforeSave(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $subject
    ) {
        $newDateTo = date('Y-m-d h:m:s', strtotime("+90 day"));
        $from = $subject->getNewsFromDate();
        $to = $subject->getNewsToDate();
        if ($from && $to) {
            $subject->setNewsToDate($newDateTo);
        }

        return [];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to create a custom extension with the following :

> MyModule/DatesFix/registration.php

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'MyModule_DatesFix',
    __DIR__
);
```

> MyModule/DatesFix/etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="MyModule_DatesFix" setup_version="1.0.0"></module>
</config>
```

> MyModule/DatesFix/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product">
        <plugin disabled="false" name="new_to_datefix" sortOrder="10" type="MyModule\DatesFix\Plugin\NewToDate"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

In the above `di.xml` file we have declared the `name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product"` , this refers to the class whose method we are going to override .

so you can find all the related methods that you can use by going to `vendor/module-catalog/Model/Product.php` file .

> MyModule/DatesFix/Plugin/NewToDate.php

```
<?php 

namespace MyModule\DatesFix\Plugin;

class NewToDate
{
    public function beforeSave($subject){
        $new_to_date = date('m/d/Y',strtotime("+90 days"));

        if (!$subject->getNewsToDate()) {
            $subject->setNewsToDate($new_to_date); 
        }
    }
}
```